# jQuery Submit AJAX Form from Different Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have a Rails 3.0 app that has a perfectly-working AJAX-ified form. For each of the input fields I have used jQuery to bind the submit() action for the form:

```
$("#profile_form :input").live('change', function() {
$("#profile_form").submit();
});
```

In another part of this form I have a popup dialogue; it opens in a new window. When its work is complete, I want it to command this form to submit. However, it doesn't work as expected:

```
var doc = window.opener.document;
$("#profile_form", doc).submit();
```

Rather than submit the form as JS, it submits as HTML, and the page refreshes to blank rather than in place, in the background (notably, in both cases the action is completed and the new data is saved. So there's that, anyway).

I've tried forcing the form itself to submit as Javascript (using :format => :js in the :url hash on the form action), but then the page refreshes to show the raw Javascript from the update action.

I fathom there's some security policy that I'm possibly contravening, trying to submit a form from a different page. But I can't help but think there's a way around this. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the form's submit action? What is happening on submit? You may be able to hook into that directly.

Comment: The submit action is a controller action in Rails. Are you suggesting that I gather the form's input fields and POST them to the action's URL instead of trying to trigger the submit event?

Comment: No, I'm saying in the actual rendered html, what happens? Sorry, I'm relatively unfamiliar with Rails. I'm guessing that the form has a submit handler which prevents default action, and instead uses some sort of javascript, possibly to an ajax call?

Comment: The form has a data-remote attribute set to true. On form submit it makes an AJAX call to a Rails controller. It's just that, when told to submit from another page, it ignores the ajax...